# Compile freedink couldn't find SDL2

Tags: bash, debian, compiling, gnu

I tried to compile GNU Freedink as described in the BUILD file but when I try to configure it couldn't find SDL2.
Log: http://pastebin.com/GYHHa4T0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the build-dependencies:

```
apt-get build-dep freedink
```

That will ensure all the files required to build Freedink are available, but with SDL 1.2 only. To use SDL2:

```
apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev
```

If you just want to be able to play Freedink, it's in Debian already:

```
apt-get install freedink
```

If you're trying to build the current development version (from the `git` repository for example), you'll need to build the current development versions of the various SDL dependencies; Freedink expects newer versions than have been released. The [BUILD](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freedink.git/tree/BUILD) file lists the bug fixes needed on top of the current releases.

You could try modifying [configure.ac](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freedink.git/tree/configure.ac) so the versions aren't compared strictly; line 140:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([SDL2], [sdl2 >= 2.0  SDL2_image >= 2.0.0 SDL2_mixer >= 2.0.0 SDL2_ttf >= 2.0.12 SDL2_gfx >= 1.0.0],
```

but you'll come across the bugs mentioned in the BUILD file...

Comment: Unfortunately the released version of SDL2 isn't new enough for Freedisk, you'll need to build SDL2 yourself if you want to build the current development version of Freedink. (Or you could modify the requirements in [configure.ac](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freedink.git/tree/configure.ac) to use `>=` rather than `>` on line 140...).

Comment: I edited the file but it still gives me this error:
Errors and warnings recap:
* You need to install the SDL libraries:
Requested 'SDL2_image > 2.0.0' but version of SDL2_image is 2.0.0
Requested 'SDL2_mixer > 2.0.0' but version of SDL2_mixer is 2.0.0
Requested 'SDL2_ttf > 2.0.12' but version of SDL2_ttf is 2.0.12

Comment: Could you try running `./bootstrap clean` in the source tree? (After changing `configure.ac` you need to re-generate `configure`.) Then try the build again...

Comment: It gives this out:http://pastebin.com/aCQR9u23
and says it can't find configure.

Comment: How about `./bootstrap` before `./configure`? (Without `clean`.)

Comment: Ok worked but freedink can't find a reference directory any idea?

Comment: I think it's looking for its data files; playing around with `--refdir` might help.